# Android: Incrementing EditText

Tags: android, user-interface, preferences

I'm currently working on the Preferences of my Application and I have to set an Angle. The default value will be something like 30° and the user should be able to adjust this angle so that it suits best.

Instead of just making a ordinary EditTextPreference I want it to be adjustable like it is in other apps.

For example in the Calendar app:

[image: Wanted functionality like in the Calendar]

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and therefor I'm asking before I start to implement such a GUI element by myself.

Does anybody know if something already exists?

Greetings,
Peter

Comment: It's called Dale Handwritten FFT. It's in this package: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monotype.android.font.pack.hand&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5tb25vdHlwZS5hbmRyb2lkLmZvbnQucGFjay5oYW5kIl0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a  [Number Picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).
I guess this should suit your needs, doesn't it?

Comment: It seems so. I look into this in a hour and then I'll accept your answer. Thank you. ;)

Comment: You're welcome :)
I think by using a [PopUpWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) where the NumberPicker is set as the view (`setContentView(View view)`) you will achieve a similar functionality like in your example above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can modify the [Android Holo Pickers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html). The UI kinda looks similar. There is a [library](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) that backports this all the way to Android 2.2 that might help you.